# Missing number treated as zero

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

I am getting `Missing number treated as zero` error when I type the following code in my document. But when I wrote it in a new document, everything seems OK.

```
$\xymatrix{
A \ar[d] \ar[dr] \ar[r] & B \\
D & C }$
```

My packages are

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\input xy
\xyoption{all}
```

I would be very pleased if someone helps me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Remove `a4wide` that's a very obsolete package; moreover call Xy-pic by `\usepackage[all]{xy}` (no `\input` nor `\xyoption`).

Comment: If the code doesn't work in a bigger document, then the error probably isn't related to it, but to something before it.

Comment: Thanks for your welcoming and interest. I have changed in the original document but it does not work again. I have just learned Winedit, and sorry about if it is an easy question. When I deleted xymatrix part then everything is Ok. Besides when I wrote it in a new document then it is Ok, also. Probably, it is because of the something before. But I only have some abbreviations of some characters. For instance i HAVE \d instead \delta.

Comment: Sorry, but without an example of code that goes wrong it's impossible to say more.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\input xy
\xyoption{all}
\begin{document}
$\xymatrix{
A \ar[d] \ar[dr] \ar[r] & B \\
D & C }$ 
\end{document}
```

compiles fine for me using TL12 (frozen).

Comment: Hi; I found the mistake. One of the definitions I've had \def\char{{\rm char }}. When I deleted it then its Ok. I don't why, but it works. Thanks for all your comments and interest.

Comment: `\char` is a primitive TeX command no doubt used internally in xypic, so redefining it will lead to disaster.

Comment: Basically never use `\def` unless you really know what you are doing. For users it is much safer to use `\newcommand`, it will complain if the macro already exist, in which case one can redefine it (`\renewcommand`) if you know exactly what it does.